# Can somebody help me building up an @Query that can be used with MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mongodb-query

I have laid out the Java architecture according to my requirement but is struggling with the formation of query part.

The architecture is as follows

```
Class AbcRequest{
List<Filters> filters;
}

Class Filters{
String abcCode;
List<String> abcType;
}

Class abcController{
getFilters(List<String>someList, boolean status, AbcRequest request){
for(Filters filter: request.getFilters(){
String abcCode = filter.getAbcCode();
List<String> abcTypes = filter.getAbcType();
  }
 }
}
```

Now I want to pass these values to a repository and get the list of required queries from DB based on it.

My query should have a condition like :
where ((someList in ('a','b') and status='false' and abcCode='8' and abcType in ('done','pending') OR (someList in ('a','b') and status='false' and abcCode='6' and abcType in ('pending'))

How to write a MongoDB @Query to get such a query out of the repository method.
It is a mixture of many 'AND' along with combination of 'OR'
Like for example :-- where (a AND b AND c AND d) OR (a AND e AND f AND d)

I know how to use simple OR with @Query:-  Like building a query for example (where A=10 OR B=10)
@Query('$or' : [{A:10},{B:10}])

But query that I wanted to build is a bit complex and am struggling with it. Also I don't want to use Criteria because I have to deal with return types. Best is to use @Query and I have been instructed to use @Query as well.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mayme you can try this:

```
Query query = new Query();
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        Criteria a = new Criteria();
        a.andOperator(Criteria.where("someList").in(Arrays.asList("A","B")),Criteria.where(
                "status").is(false),Criteria.where("abcCode").is(6),....)
        // B is the same as a
        Criteria b = new Criteria();
        //...
        
        criteria.orOperator(a,b);
        query.addCriteria(criteria);
```

Comment: Hi fan, Thanks for your answer. I cannot use criteria due to some restrictions. I have to use `@Query` for the same. An Idea how to implement the same using `Query`. Thanks!

Comment: ok, you can learn something about `MongoRepository`. Use `@Query("{'abcCode': '6', 'status': false}")`, Use native SQL directly through annotations `@Query`

Answer (score 0):

We specify the `targetUserId` with the `user_id` you want to filter by.

We add a `$match` stage at the beginning of the aggregation pipeline to filter documents with the specified `user_id`.

The rest of the aggregation pipeline remains the same as before, calculating the sum of account balances for the specified user.

We then check if the result contains data for the specified user and print the user's total balance, or print a message if the user is not found or has no accounts.

Make sure to replace `mongodb://localhost:27017/your-database-name` with your actual MongoDB connection string and adjust the schema to match your data structure if needed.

```
// Connect to the MongoDB database using the Liquid ORM's Database module
const db = await Database.connect('mongodb');

// Access the "bank_accounts" collection within the database
const accountsCollection = db.collection('bank_accounts');

// Define an aggregation pipeline to filter and group account data
const aggregationPipeline = [
  {
    // Stage 1: Match documents where the user_id matches the currently targetUserId 
    $match: {
      user_id: targetUserId,
    },
  },
  {
    // Stage 2: Group the matched documents by user_id and calculate the total balance
    $group: {
      _id: '$user_id', // Group by user_id
      totalBalance: { $sum: { $toDouble: '$account_balance' } }, // Calculate the sum of account_balance
    },
  },
];

// Execute the aggregation pipeline and store the result in the "result" variable
const result = await accountsCollection.aggregate(aggregationPipeline).toArray();

console.log("result" ,result);

// Check if there are accounts found for the user
if (result.length > 0) {
  // Log the total account balance for the user
  console.log('Total account balance:', result[0].totalBalance);

  // Update the "total_balance" field in the UserModel for the user
  await UserModel.query().where("slug", request.user().slug).update({"total_balance": result[0].totalBalance});
} else {
  // Log a message indicating that no accounts were found for the user
  console.log('No accounts found.');
}
```